# Redirect from one controller method to another controller method

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I am using Spring 3 and Tiles 2 in my application and have a bit of trouble with redirecting.
Preferably, I would like to be able to just call or redirect from a Controller1 method to Controller2 method, but so far have been unsuccessful.

I have tried to create a new entry in the pageviews.properties file. That way I could just return this name from Controller1 and it would look up my tiles def name from the xml files.

```
createRejectionEmail.(parent)=tilesView
createRejectionEmail.url=createRejectionEmail.page

redirectRejectionEmail.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView
rediectRejectionEmail.contextRelative=true
redirectRejectionEmail.url=createRejectionEmail.page
```

But, when I try returning like shown below my the URL contains createRejectionEmail as part of the URL  - instead of using that to do the look up in the tiles defs.
    mav.setViewName("redirectRejectionEmail");
    return mav;

```
<definition name="createRejectionEmail.page" extends="brandedLayout">
  <put-attribute name="targetFunction" value="status" />
  <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB  INF/jsp/pages/status/createRejectionEmail.jsp" />
</definition>
```

My current config is below.

```
<bean id="resourceViewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver"
p:order="0" p:basename="config.spring.viewresolution.pageviews"/>



<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
<property name="definitions">
   <list>
  <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/**/views.xml</value>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

From your controller you can change the return type to be a ModelAndView and return code below. This will re-direct the request and call the controller for the new URL.

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/myURL");
```

Alternatively you could take in the HttpServletResponse in your controller method and return a redirect.

```
public void myController(HttpServletResponse response){
response.sendRedirect("/myURL");
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I tried this and I get the following.Could not resolve view with name 'redirect:/myapppath/status/displayEmailRejectionForm.html' in servlet with name 'Spring-MVC-for-OA'. SHoudl I be using a different view resolver? Currently, we are using the ResourceBundleViewResolver with tiles2

Comment: OK Whew! It's working! Thank you so much for your help. I also had to add the UrlBasedViewResolver to my application context. I really appreciate you taking the time to respond!

Comment: This seems to be working fine even with String return type for the @RequestMapping annotated methods. Like in Carl's case the key is to add the UrlBasedViewResolver class configuration.

Comment: This works for me without any modifications. using spring 4.1+ and hibernate 5.0+.

Comment: this is vary userfull

Answer (score 9):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/timeout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loginForm(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {


                return new ModelAndView("redirect:/app/timeout");

    }
```

When this method handler call then it redirect to the /app/timeout controller.

Comment: Works like a charm, and the best is that if your application have context then the this method solve it without need to pass explicitly.