# GET Request - Redirect to another page and keep params

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm building an app with Spring MVC and I want to redirect to another url, but I want to keep the param.

This is what I have in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirect(
    @RequestParam(value = "name") String name,
    @RequestParam(value = "surname") String name,
    RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes
) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("surname", surname);
    return String.format("redirect:/users/name/%s", name);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users/name/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String view(
    @PathVariable("name") String name,
    Model model,
    @RequestParam(value = "surname") String surname
) {
  ...
}
```

For example, when I hit `/users/?name=mark&surname=williams`, I want to be redirected to `users/name/mark?surname=williams`

However, I am being redirected but the params disappear. If I set a blocker in Intellij, I can see it receives the params but they are not displayed.

Comment: Did you try  `addAttribute()` instead of `.addFlashAttribute()`?

Comment: I did, it was the same

Comment: For some reason my page is redirecting twice, I think the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect() :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirect(
    @RequestParam(value = "name") String name,
    @RequestParam(value = "surname") String surname,
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse
) throws IOException {
    httpResponse.sendRedirect("/CONTEXT-ROOT/users/name/"+ name+"?surname="+surname);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users/name/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String view(
    @PathVariable("name") String name,
    @RequestParam(value = "surname") String surname
) {
  System.out.println("surname="+surname);
  return "{\"response\":\"ok\"}";
}
```

To make redirect: work, you may need to add a UrlBasedViewResolver.

Check this question : [Redirect from one controller method to another controller method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218856/redirect-from-one-controller-method-to-another-controller-method)